# Audio not working with Logitech G930 headset with Arch Linux

Tags: audio, arch-linux, logitech-headset

I have recently installed Arch Linux via Architect and came across a problem with my headset. I don't get any audio from my headset except system beeps. I can still control the volume with the scroller on my headset. I need help getting audio to work. I have pulseaudio and alsa installed.

EDIT:
[Here](http://pastebin.com/WzFQMPFZ) are the results of alsa-info.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. For future reference, I rebooted and used gnome instead of KDE. From there I used pavucontrol to set as default

Answer (score 0):

Run `alsamixer` in terminal.

Press F6 to select sound card.(In most conditions, you dont need to do this, because the default sound card is which you need it to work)

Use arrow keys to select "Master" "Headphone" or other related items. While selecting, use M key to unmute those channels.

After that, you might hear voice from you favorite headphone.

Comment: That did not seem to help although I did find that "headphones" in my main sound card was off.